# Set div height to height of browser using CSS ONLY

Tags: html, css, height

*I am Making a Layout using CSS **ONLY**.

and  I'm trying to do is have the `header` div take up a set amount of pixels in height, say 100px but then the `content` div to take up the rest of the browser window's height.

Ie the browser windows height less the height of the header div.

So HTML is as follows,

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

....and here is the CSS I've got so far.

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}

#header {width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: #333;}

#content {position: relative; top: 10px; width: 100%; /*height: auto !important;*/  min-height: 100%; background-color: #999; }
```

I know, because I've done it that this is possible to do with JS/Jquery to set the content div's height based on the height of the browser, but I'd love to know if there's a way of doing this just using CSS.

As you can see from the Fiddle below, the current CSS just makes the content div shoot off the screen at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/PysLY/

Comment: why you put height auto in comments content is taking whole remaining remaining height

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got this result: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC7BT/

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}

#header {width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: #333;}

#content {width: 100%; min-height: calc(100% - 100px); background-color: #999; overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks @rafaeldefazio.  Never knew about css calc but from the looks of your fiddle, does the trick! Nice one.